# EntityCommandException on Linq with group by and count

Tags: c#, linq, join, linq-group

I am facing EntityCommandException when I try to print out LINQ results. This is my code:

```
var contacts = from c in db.mydata
               join r in db.contacts on c.user equals r.user 
               group c by new { c.user, r.name }
               into g
               orderby g.Count() descending
               select new { name= g.Key.name , counter = g.Count() } ;

foreach (var co in contacts )
{
    Console.Write(co.name);
}
```

The exception is at the foreach line. If in the foreach loop I print `Console.Write(co.counter);`, the exception doesn't show up.

Comment: Can you post some details about the exception ?

Comment: I have this in InnerException : {"Unknown column 'GroupBy1.K2' in 'field list'"}

Comment: The problem disappears if I remove from the LINQ code the Count() functions  ex. : var contacts = from c in db.mydata
               join r in db.contacts on c.user equals r.user 
               group c by new { c.user, r.name }
               into g
 Thanks @BasBrekelmans              
               select new { name= g.Key.name  } ;